# Good practices with entities when creating a bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, bundle

I would like to create a bundle with some entities inside but how is the user of my bundle supposed to add a field to my entities if he wants to?

There is some case where the **user may want to add fields** to the **entities of my bundle** but he cannot modify the source files of my bundle in the vendor.

Should I abandon the idea to let a user add fields to my bundle's entities? Or what is the correct way to let him do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to suggest to the user in your documenation that they extend your base entity class.

FOS userbundle suggests this, and can be seen here in [this tutorial document](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/09/symfony-3-and-fos-user-bundle-customizing-users.html)

It really should be as simple as that.

You could also create a [mapped superclass](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) (probably abstract) so the user can extend those if needed.  This approach is useful if you have multiple child entity classes from some kind of 'core' parent class which provides standard state or functionality.

Comment: Is a trait a good solution aswell ? If not i may suggest it in the documentation or use a mapped superclass as you recommended. As i see there are multiple solution but there is no officiel recommendation about that ?

Comment: id not use a trait as youll have to provide the annotations so that doctrine knows where to find everything.  If you use a trait you wont be able to control the class annotations